# The remaining blue color in ::selection?

Tags: css, selection

The `::selection { }` CSS element selector is supposed to replace the default blue-colored text selection with our own choice of text and background color.

However, this seems not always the case, as I often see websites which has the remaining blue color. It's not completely replaced with our owh choice of color.

**======EDIT======**

I guess it's easier to see by our own eyes rather than through screenshot.

See this page for example: [bleachindonesia.com/2012/05/27/bleach-day](http://bleachindonesia.com/2012/05/27/bleach-day)

On that page, if you  try to select all (Ctrl+A), you would see the text will be blocked/selected with gray color. Yes, because the page CSS employs `::selection, ::-moz-selection { background:#59574b;color:#fdfcf5; }`.

However, as you can see with the screenshot below, it leaves some default, blue-colored selection on some part.

[image: Notice the blue color among the gray here.]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0aUJ.png

Notice the color difference, and at the same time, the unselected part. There are some parts on the site that gets selected with the default blue-colored ::selection, but at the same time there are also some other parts that doesn't get selected.

---

Meanwhile, there is also this page: [24ways.org/2005/swooshy-curly-quotes-without-images](http://24ways.org/2005/swooshy-curly-quotes-without-images)

Again,  try to select all (Ctrl+A) the page. You could see all selection is perfectly maroon-colored. There is no default blue-colored selection. There is only parts that doesn't get selected, but there is no the default blue-colored selection. As pictured by the screenshot below:

[image: Perfectly colored]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4o6ll.png

The page CSS? `::selection { background-color: rgba(179, 45, 71, .75); color: #fff; }`. The only difference with the first page that it uses RGBA and not hex code. I don't think it makes any difference there--it's essentially the same code.

Now what makes me wonder.

Why is on the first page the default blue-colored select persists, but it doesn't persist on the second page? And, how to make it as perfect as the second page?

Comment: I don't get it, what's supposed to be selected in that image?

Comment: Please provide a link to your page, and post the relevant CSS here.

Comment: @xception: sorry for the confusing explanation, I've edited the post. Perhaps it's easier if you see the website itself and Ctrl+A. Please wait, I'll be providing the links

Comment: @Abody97: since my site is still on localhost, I'd give example on here > http://bleachindonesia.com/2012/05/27/bleach-day/ < on this site, if you Ctrl+A, you could see some default blue color among the custom black-colored selection. Meanwhile, if you see here >  http://24ways.org/2005/swooshy-curly-quotes-without-images < you could see all selection is maroon-colored (customized), except in some parts (colored green, which is intended). There is no blue color left, and it's perfectly colored as maroon.

Comment: You mention that you're "doing something", but yet we don't see what it is you've done. Please include the relevant CSS in your question and a minimal demo on http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: @JaredFarrish It's not a problem I'm having while I'm creating a website. It's a behavior I've been noticing in various websites. So I'm afraid I can't give a demo (since that would mean I have to copy two entire different websites). However, I have tried to re-outline what I want to ask by editing my question. Please do re-check and visit those two sites I have linked above. :)

Comment: Oh, I see. There's two differences I notice: the 24 Ways site is using `media="screen"` and the other isn't, and the selection text that's blue seems to be where there's a `margin` set. I don't know if that starts to get to the root of the problem, but that's the first things I notice.

Comment: This replicates the problem in Chrome (at least): http://jsfiddle.net/RfPgt/ It seems to be when an element is nested within another element which itself has selectable elements.

Comment: @Jared: It's seen in Safari as well.

Comment: @JaredFarrish defining where things float (left or right) fixes this. It's a hard one to go back and add to CSS without having to remake the whole page, but something to bear in mind. http://jsfiddle.net/RfPgt/20

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Frankly, it's very difficult to tell if this is buggy behavior, although I'd surmise that it looks very much like it. `::selection` suffered from a lack of proper definition (and thus a lack of proper implementation and testing), so I bet even browser vendors have had trouble figuring out what's wrong.

Worth mentioning is that this rule, from the first site:

```
::selection, ::-moz-selection { background:#59574b;color:#fdfcf5; }
```

Seems very much benign, except it incorrectly combines `::selection` and `::-moz-selection` such that it will never work in Firefox, because it doesn't recognize `::selection` and [drops the whole rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302172/firefox-moz-selection-selector-bug-is-there-a-workaround/5302221#5302221). 24ways.org doesn't display the selection color properly in Firefox either, not because of combined selectors but because there is no `::-moz-selection` selector in the first place.

As to why Chrome and Safari leave blue areas of highlight in certain areas in the first site, I really don't know. However, I think [Jared Farrish makes a good point](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/17066040):

> This replicates the problem in Chrome (at least): [jsfiddle.net/RfPgt](http://jsfiddle.net/RfPgt) It seems to be when an element is nested within another element which itself has selectable elements.

Comment: Here's a couple of more situations where it fails (as well as doesn't, like a `div` with `style="display: inline"`): http://jsfiddle.net/RfPgt/2/

Comment: Great answer. I also found that having an img set as "display:block" wrapped inside of an "<a>" tag would cause issues. As soon as I did "display: inline-block;" the problem was solved

Comment: actually, you should not comma seperate them because of the dropping of both rules when it finds one invalid.  you must do `::selection{background:black}` and `::-moz-selection{background:black}` in two different sets

Comment: It appears to be a bug, see answer to this question which gives a link to the webkit bug ID: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866866/why-does-the-css3-pseudo-selection-not-change-the-color-for-all-parts

Comment: As I put in the answer above; defining where things float (left or right) fixes this. It's a hard one to go back and add to CSS without having to remake the whole page, but something to bear in mind. http://jsfiddle.net/RfPgt/20

Answer (score 1):

I found what is causing this. It is `<br>` so if you have `<br>` in your text try deleting it

Answer (score -1):

I read this question some time ago to find a solution for the same problem but I did not find it. Now, even if the question is old, I want to share the solution that I found.

Just use the universal selector:

```
*::selection { background:red; }
```

Comment: This did not fix the problem for me