# ::selection in Chrome or Tumblr bug?

Tags: css, google-chrome, selection, tumblr

So I wanted to style selection on my Tumblr blog differently, and it works great in Mozilla, but when it comes to Chrome when I put this code:

```
::selection {
    background:{color:Body Text};
    color:{color:Entry Background};
}

::-moz-selection {
    background:{color:Body Text};
    color:{color:Entry Background};
}

::-webkit-selection {
    background:{color:Body Text};
    color:{color:Entry Background};
}
```

colors aren't right.

Test [here](http://neonsignslp3colors.tumblr.com/) - try both Mozilla and Chrome and you'll see what I'm talking about.

I also wanted to see if maybe the problem was in using Tumblr color codes [*{color:Body Text}*] but the same thing happens if I use regular color codes [*#555555*].

There is also this [demo](http://paulmaloney.net/demo/selection.html) where ::selection works perfectly in Chrome, even without that annoying additional blue selection part.

Is there a way to get rid of that blue selection part?

Or any solutions for the whole issue?

Here's a screenshot of what the question is asking:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot and describe *exactly* what the problem is? (Maybe we don't see what you're talking about; maybe it's just your computer. `:)`)

Comment: There is no `::-webkit-selection`. Also, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650767/the-remaining-blue-color-in-selection

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8866876/900747

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8866866/900747

Comment: It's not a duplicate of anything, none of those issues are referring to Chrome making colors different than written, and blue section question wasn't the main problem.

Comment: I would guess it has to do with the <br> tags
You can find more info [here][1].

Could you test adding <br> tags to your test code?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899252/can-you-target-br-with-css

Comment: I asked a similar question some time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650767/the-remaining-blue-color-in-selection According to Jared Farrish, the problem seems to happen "when an element is nested within another element which itself has selectable elements."