# CSS3 ::selection doesn't cover entire page

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a webshop, I am using following CSS3 to change the style of selected content by following CSS:

```
::selection {
    background-color:#5f2f8f;
    color:white;
}
```

It does work, but when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> you still see the `default` selection on some spaces (the blue stuff).

Why is there still default selection style on some spaces after pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>?

[<kbd>**Live demo**</kbd>](http://www.zonwering-jaloezieen.nl/jaloezieen-deluxe/)

**Image demo:**

[image]

Comment: It's mostly because browser implementations of `::selection` are very poor.

Comment: @BoltClock, I wouldn't say poor. Why should you be able to highlight margins and paddings?

Answer (score 0):

Question Duplicate of:[Why does the CSS3 pseudo ::selection not change the color for all parts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866866/why-does-the-css3-pseudo-selection-not-change-the-color-for-all-parts)

He said!

> The only workaround I've been able to come up with is using
>   " `contenteditable` " elements instead of "`<input>` "elements.

### Originally Posted From : "ThinkingStiff"

Make sure to check out his Full post : [CSS3 - How to style the selected text in textareas and inputs in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438418/css3-how-to-style-the-selected-text-in-textareas-and-inputs-in-chrome/8529323#8529323)