# Display selection when textarea loses focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form with a text box and a button:

```html
<p><textarea rows="4" cols="30">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</textarea></p>
<p><input type="button" value="Click me"></p>
```

The user makes a text selection, then clicks on the button. As textarea loses focus, selection is no longer visible.

Is there a way to make the selection remain visible? It doesn't need to be usable (i.e., there's no need that e.g. typing removes the selection or <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> copies it) but I'd expect some kind of visual feedback that the textarea contains a selection.

[image: Mockup]

Comment: Have you seen this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438418/css3-how-to-style-the-selected-text-in-textareas-and-inputs-in-chrome it might be helpfull

Comment: But the textarea *doesn't* contain a selection anymore when it loses focus (at least on my Chrome). So the question AFAICT should be "how to have textarea retain selected text when it loses focus".

Comment: @Juhana - Trust me, it does keep the selection, even if it gets lost when you focus back. My full code makes use of it successfully.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646611/programmatically-selecting-partial-text-in-an-input-field

Comment: @inser - I don't want to create a selection, I already have one (the one created by the user).

Comment: @Ateszki - I'm aware of the [`::selection` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/::selection) but there doesn't seem to be a style for non-active elements.

Comment: Actually on jsFiddle, if you select some text in one frame and click somewhere else, the selection remains visible, just like the way you describe it.

Comment: @Antony - That's right. `<iframe>` as WildCrustacean suggests?

Comment: @Antony, JSFiddle doesn't use iFrames for the frames (CSS, HTML, Javascript). It's actually quite interesting, they use normal `<div>`s and other HTML elements, they intercept the keyboard events and modify the HTML layout. Use a debugger and check it, I especially liked the way they blink the typing cursor (I don't know the correct name).

Comment: @Adnan It's called a blinking cursor :)

Comment: @Adnan It looks like jsFiddle has got quite a bit of hack into this. The selection is created by JavaScript ([codemirror.js](http://jsfiddle.net/js/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js?ThereIsNoSpring)) and the style is applied through CSS ([codemirror.css](http://jsfiddle.net/js/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css?ThereIsNoSpring)) (the color of the selection is defined by `.CodeMirror-selected { background: #d9d9d9; }`).

Answer (score 6):

After digging through jsFiddle, I found that [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) has everything you need to create a highly customized textarea. It was built for writing codes but with a small trick, it can be applied to textareas in general.

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/K4xG2/2/embedded/result/)

First have a textarea ready:

```html
<textarea id="a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</textarea>
```

Then place the following script after it to create a CodeMirror textarea, and provide additional settings to convert it to a normal textarea.

- `mode`: I use `"none"` here to remove syntax highlighting.
- `lineWrapping`: use `true` to wrap for long lines.

```javascript
var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("a"), {
    mode: "none",
    lineWrapping: true
});
```

Finally, use CSS to control the size and make it look like a standard textarea:

```css
.CodeMirror {
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<textarea onblur="this.focus()">this is a test</textarea>
<p><input type="button" value="Click me"></p>
```

This works as expected with IE/Chrome. But not with FF.

---

So here is a general solution:

```
<textarea onblur="doBlur(this)">this is a test</textarea>
<p><input type="button" value="Click me"></p>

<script>
function doBlur(obj) {
  setTimeout(function() { obj.focus(); }, 10);
}
</script>
```

Comment: this doesn't work if you are doing anything that takes less than 10 ms, for example opening an md-menu

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap the `textarea` in an `iframe`, that still shows the selection within the frame when the button is clicked.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bdeldri/ZL9PG/) uses the `srcdoc` attribute, which is only supported by Chrome and Safari 6. You could still use an `iframe` without that attribute though.

EDIT: Here is a [new even hackier fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bdeldri/hZBw4/) that uses jquery to add the `iframe`, works at least in Chrome and FF (IE doesn't allow data URIs in an `iframe` for security reasons)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the effect I'm looking for. Sadly, I'd need to completely redesign my form logic to handle this hack.

Comment: Doesn't work in Firefox. But works in Chrome, so +1 for the nice idea.

Comment: @Adnan this would work in all browsers, just not this specific example.

Answer (score 3):

I know this isn't technically what you wanted, but I'm going to cheat anyways.

Javascript:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
var div = document.getElementById('holder');

var original_value = textarea.value;
textarea.onblur = function () {
    var start = textarea.selectionStart;
    var end = textarea.selectionEnd;
    textarea.style.display = "none";
    div.innerHTML = textarea.value.splice(end, 0, "</span>").splice(start, 0, "<span>");
    div.style.display = "block";
}

div.onclick = function () {
    div.style.display = "none";
    textarea.style.display = "block";
    textarea.value = original_value;
}

String.prototype.splice = function( idx, rem, s ) {
    return (this.slice(0,idx) + s + this.slice(idx + Math.abs(rem)));
};
```

HTML:

```
<p><textarea id="textarea" rows="4" cols="30">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</textarea></p>
<div id="holder"></div>
<p><input id="click" type="button" value="Click me"></p>
```

CSS:

```
textarea, #holder{
    height: 120px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-family: Arial;
}
#holder{    
    display: none;
}
#holder span{
    background-color: #b4d5ff;
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Mb89X/4/

Comment: Replace the `<textarea>` with a `<span>` on the fly? Witty xD

Comment: Could you explain where `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` come from? I'm trying to understand your code....

Comment: Pretty neat idea. Also, you look like Michael from Vsauce.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is not possible with a textarea.

Instead of using a textarea, I would suggest using a `div` with `contenteditable="true"` and [rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/). Then wrap the selected text or select the text on focus and blur events.

This rangy demo demonstrates how to select text:
http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/highlighter.html

Answer (score 2):

Taking the idea from @Prisoner, I'd like improve further until it's feels like a natural behaviour with scrolling and resizing functionality.

The main idea is the same. I also made full demo with comments **[here](https://codepen.io/willnode/pen/qxvxKB)**. I repost below for the context of this question.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var div = document.getElementById('holder');

function syncSize() {
    div.style.width = (input.scrollWidth - 4) + "px";
    div.style.height = input.style.height;
}

new MutationObserver(syncSize).observe(input, {
    attributes: true,
    attributeFilter: ["style"]
});

syncSize();

input.onchange = () => syncSize();

input.onblur = () => {
    var start = input.selectionStart;
    var end = input.selectionEnd;
    var text = input.value;
    div.innerHTML = text.substring(0, start) +
        "<span>" + text.substring(start, end) +
        "</span>" + text.substring(end);
    div.style.display = "block";
}

input.onfocus = () => div.style.display = "none";

input.onscroll = () => div.style.top = -input.scrollTop + "px";

input.value = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";

input.select();
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative; 
  overflow: hidden;
}

#input {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
}

#holder, #input {
    padding: 2px;
    font: 400 13.3333px monospace;
    border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

#holder {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    color: transparent;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: transparent;
}

#holder span {
    background-color: #c8c8c8;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <textarea id="input"></textarea>
  <div id="holder"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `:focus` of the button doen't matter, you could use

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function () {
    $('textarea').focus();
});
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cErLK/1/).

Comment: Funnily enough, it's a hack that might do the trick in my full code because all I have is a select and a button—nothing that needs to be focused in order to work. I definitively need to test that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var element = document.getElementById('text')
if(element.setSelectionRange)
{
    element.focus();
    element.setSelectionRange(2, 10);    
}
else if(element.createTextRange)
{

    var selRange = element.createTextRange();
          selRange.collapse(true);
          selRange.moveStart('character', 2);
          selRange.moveEnd('character', 10);
          selRange.select();
          field.focus();
} else if( typeof element.selectionStart != 'undefined' ) {
      element.selectionStart = 2;
      element.selectionEnd = 10;
      element.focus();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/inser/YJzvb/2/

Comment: I think you misread the question. If we [add a button](http://jsfiddle.net/hTRZL/), your code behaves like mine. You are only creating a selection programmatically—I don't want to create a selection, I already have one. I just want to make it *visible*.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small jQuery plugin which modifies a specified `<textarea>` element when invoked, adding a grayed out selection when the element is unfocused.

```js
// jQuery plugin to make textarea selection visible when unfocused.                                                                                                                                      
// Achieved by adding an underlay with same content with <mark> around                                                                                                                                   
// selected text. (Scroll in textarea not supported, resize is.)                                                                                                                                         
$.fn.selectionShadow = function () {
  const $input = this
  const prop = n => parseInt($input.css(n))
  const $wrap = $input.wrap('<div>').parent()   // wrapper                                                                                                                                               
    .css({
      ...Object.fromEntries(
        'display width height font background resize margin overflowWrap'
          .split(' ').map(x => [x, $input.css(x)])),
      position: 'relative',
      overflow: 'hidden',
      border: 0,
      padding: ['top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left'].map(
        x => prop(`padding-${x}`) + prop(`border-${x}-width`) + 'px'
      ).join(' '),
    })
  const $shadow = $('<span>').prependTo($wrap)  // shadow-selection                                                                                                                                      
    .css({ color: 'transparent' })
  $input                                        // input element                                                                                                                                         
    .on('focusin',  () => $shadow.hide())       //   hide shadow if focused                                                                                                                              
    .on('focusout', () => $shadow.show())
    .on('select', evt => {                      //   if selection change                                                                                                                                 
      const i = evt.target                      //     update shadow                                                                                                                                     
      const [x, s, a] = [i.value ?? '', i.selectionStart, i.selectionEnd]
      $shadow.html(x.slice(0, s) + '<mark class=selectionShadow>' +
                   x.slice(s, a) + '</mark>' + x.slice(a))
    })
    .css({
      boxSizing: 'border-box',
      position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0,
      overflow: 'hidden',
      display: 'block',
      background: 'transparent',
      resize: 'none',
      margin: 0,
    })
  $('head').append(
    `<style>mark.selectionShadow { background: #0003; color: transparent }`)
}
```

Invoke the plugin by with `$('textarea').selectionShadow()`.

The above works by adding an 'underlay' to the textarea, and making sure that the underlay have the exact same padding, font style, and word wrapping rules, so that the text of the textarea and the underlay will precisely overlap. Whenever selection in updated the underlay is also updated, and the current selection is marked with `<mark>`, which is styled with a gray background (text color is set to `transparent` in the underlay, so as not to interfere with the antialias edges of the text).

I wrote the above for a web page of mine, but YMMV. Use freely!