# Apply style to selected text in a textbox

Tags: jquery, css, textbox, styles

I have the following code

```
   $('#txtEditor').select(function (e) {
        var start = e.target.selectionStart;
        var end = e.target.selectionEnd;
        selText = $('#txtEditor').val().substring(start, end);
    });

<asp:TextBox ID="txtEditor" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="500px" Height="500px" Font-Size="Large"></asp:TextBox>
```

I want to apply some style (colour it or make it bold or ittallic etc) only to the selected text (after selection) in the textbox. In `selText` Im getting the selected string. But I couldn't find any event or function which will apply style only to the selected string in the textbox.

Comment: add css with the following - $('selector').css('name', 'value');

Comment: Could [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438418/css3-how-to-style-the-selected-text-in-textareas-and-inputs-in-chrome) be an option for you?

Comment: Textbox can have a plenty of text in it I need to apply style only to the selected text. Like what we are doing with a msword or something.

Comment: Is `TextBox` equal `<textarea>` ? If it is `textarea`, you can't change the style of a part of it.

Comment: its a texbox only. Now Im using a asp:TextBox. If its an html textbox (<input type="text/>) also its fine for me.

Comment: Pls help me if anyone knows how to do this

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a HTML editor? Like the [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)?

Comment: Yes my aim is to create one. These are the priliminary doubts

Comment: I didnt get a solution yet. If its in a div its fine. But I couldn't get it done with a textbox.

Answer (score 2):

**HERE IS THE COMPLETE SOLUTION...SUDHA**

http://
js
fiddle
.net/
sandeepvirani/
mzays/

remove space between

Comment: Ehm... why put the spaces in to begin with?

Comment: @Sandeep Virani, I have tried this example. The thing is that its working for 'div' but never working for my 'textbox'. How can I modify the js file inorder to achieve my requirement?

Comment: In my textbox the content (string) is typing dynamically and I want to style a selected portion. (Like what we can do in MSWord or something)

Comment: @Mr Lister : stackoverflow can't allow me to put link of jsfiddle thats why.

Comment: I didnt get a solution yet. If its in a div its fine. But I couldn't get it done with a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of the selection part of a text on a page, use the CSS `::selection` pseudo-element.

See [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3aselection?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2F%3A%3Aselection).

Note however, that

- This is a non-standard selector, which is supported by many browsers, but not endorsed by the W3C.
- You can't change just any property, really only just colors. Not bold!

If you want to change some text inside a paragraph or something, you can use Javascript to quickly put the whole of the selection inside a new element, a `span` or something, and then apply properties to the `span`. However, if it's text in a textbox, you're out of luck, as you can't add child elements to an `input`.