# Highlight text color not background color in textarea

Tags: jquery, highlight

Highlight text color not background color  in text area area by using jquery .
I dont want background color as highlighted , The letter should get highlighted

Comment: set color like `$('textarea').css('color', 'red')`

Comment: If it is about the user selection and not the whole text, then this is probably helpful: [CSS3 - How to style the selected text in textareas and inputs in Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438418/css3-how-to-style-the-selected-text-in-textareas-and-inputs-in-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the color of the textarea using [.css('color', color)](http://api.jquery.com/css/) like

```
$('textarea').css('color', 'red')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/29aFV/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

CSS:

```
.Highlighter{     
    color: red;
 }
```

Jquery:

```
$('textarea').addClass('Highlighter');
```

Answer (score 0):

What i understood is you want to color the the text which is selected by user. I don't think thats possible that way in an input element. I suggest you to use `::selector{}` css3 selector with a `contenteditable`(*[html5 editable div attribute](http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/)*) div which can be used like text area and you can achieve what you need this way:

```
::selection{
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

and your div:

```
 <div contenteditable='true'>
      This is the dummy content.
 </div>
```

[and here you can play with fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/grp59/)