# How to change color of selected text of textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textarea

I have `textarea` and i want to change color of selected text.
Example:

```
var text = "abcdefg";
```

I want to change color of selected text `efg`.

here is my code:

```
var input = document.getElementById('area');
var value = input.value.substr(input.selectionStart, input.selectionEnd - input.selectionStart);
$('#abc').find(value).attr('color',color);
```

Comment: You can only add style to elements and text can't has color style. But you can use `::selection` css selector. See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_selection.asp

Comment: You must wrap the selected text in HTML, as textNodes cannot have style.

Comment: Why you mixed `pure JS` & `jQuery`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS3 - How to style the selected text in textareas and inputs in Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438418/css3-how-to-style-the-selected-text-in-textareas-and-inputs-in-chrome)

Answer (score 5):

Use [`::selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection) CSS selector that select part of text is seleced. You can add your CSS property to selected text of elements.

```js
var textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");
textarea.selectionStart = 12;
textarea.selectionEnd = 23;
```

```css
::-moz-selection { 
    color: red;
}
::selection {
    color: red;  
}
```

```html
<textarea>My textarea highlighted text</textarea>
```

Comment: the color that add to the text is options belongs to users. Set css like that is not suitable.

Comment: @user2956672 There is no another solution for your work. But if your color is limited, add class of color to textarea. See https://jsfiddle.net/j62p92fa/

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the `selection color` for a `textarea`, you can only change it for `non-input objects`.

Maybe you should try [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) instead of `textarea`