# Changing background color when highligted

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me? I have a textarea and three buttons with different colors.

I wanted to change the hightlighted text bgcolor when button click in javascript or css. Please help. I don't really done this, but I have a sample of CKEDITOR.

This the Sample of CKEDITOR:

[image]

This my code in textarea:

```
<textarea>
  <p> CHANGING BACKGROUND </p>
</textarea>
```

Comment: show us what you've tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change color of selected text of textarea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39656190/how-to-change-color-of-selected-text-of-textarea)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in a textarea. 
You need an `HTML Element` with `contentEditable`.

And take a look to [`document.execCommand()`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljcvtcaw.php)

Also you can simulate a `<textarea />` with CSS.

Everything is showed below:

```js
function setColor() {
    document.execCommand('backColor', false, "red");
}
```

```css
div[contentEditable] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    font: medium -moz-fixed;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    height: 28px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    resize: both;
    width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div contentEditable="true">this is some text</div>

<button onclick="setColor();">change color</button>
```